# show that $D$ is closed

Tags: real-analysis

Let $D:=\{f\in C([0,1]) : \sup_{x\in [0,1]}∥f(x)∥ \leq  1\}$ be the set of continuous function on $[0,1]$ with supremum of $|f| \leq 1$. I wish to show that $D$ is closed.

That is, if  $f_k\to f$ in $C([0,1])$, and $f_k \in D$, we need to show that $f\in D$.

Suppose that there exist sequence $f_k\to f$ in $C([0,1])$. Then $f_k \to f$ (uniformly convergence).

Since $f_k$ is uniformly convergence, $f$ is a continuous function (So $f\in C([0,1])$).

And now, to show that $f$ is in $D$, we need to show that $\sup_{x\in [0,1]} |f(x)| \leq 1$. But I don't know this part. And if this part is solved, is my proof clear?

If there is another proofs, please also let me know.

Comment: So you want to know why $D$ is not compact?

Comment: no. Actually not compact already know. But i dont know why D is closed

Comment: I suggest you to edit your question so that it states clearly what you have done and what the questions are.

Comment: Ok i delete all unnecessary parts to my question

Answer (score 1):

To show that $D$ is not compact take $f_k(x) = x^n$. They all have norm equal to $1$. This sequence doesn't have a convergent subsequence in $C([0,1])$ since it is convergent to noncontinous function

Comment: Thanks but it is my fault. I just want D is closed

Answer (score 0):

Consider $\complement D$, and pick $g \in \complement D$. Therefore, $\|g\| = 1+ \delta$, with $\delta >0$. Now, for any $f$ such that $\|f-g\| < \frac{\delta}{2}$,
$$
\|f\| \geq \|g\| - \|f-g\| \geq 1+\frac{\delta}{2} > 1,
$$
and hence $\complement D$ is an open set.

Comment: Could you show me that D is bounded?

Comment: Come on, $D$ is the closed unit ball of $C([0,1])$ with the topology of uniform convergence! It is bounded by its very own definition.